# Silverlight calling webapi behind firewall

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, silverlight-5.0

Silverlight application is sitting on a server which is accessible from internet and WebApi is sitting on a server behind firewall which is not accessible via internet but can be accessible via intranet. Both Silverlight Application Server and WebApi Server can talk in intranet. Is it possible for Silverlight application which is accessed from internet to talk to WebApi?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is the problem, then?

Comment: How can i set it up for this to work? Because right now firewall is blocking webapi calls because webapi server is sitting behind firewall and that server shouldn't be open to internet. How could we make silverlight client side application to talk to webapi without opening any firewall ports in WebApi Server.

Comment: @JotaBe any documentations or links you could direct me to?

Comment: Which is the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: There is a Silverlight Application in a server which is open to internet lets call it Green Server

There is a WebAPI  in a server which is closed for internet (Nobody outside company can access this) Lets call it Red Server. How Can a user who is accessing silverlight application from outside the company access WebAPI to get data. To me it looks like we have to move WebAPI to Green Server and since WebAPI talking to SQL Server with windows credentials there is no security issues. We don't want any proxy in between either

Comment: You're not making a good description of the network infrastructure, but you can add firewall rules that allow only Green Server to access to Red Server, through a given port. If you move red server to outside the firewall, you'll have to open access to SQL Server in the firewall, which worsens the situation. So, please, take the first path.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a firewall rule that allows Green Server to access Red Server at a given port. You can add MAC filters, IP filters, use an ad-hoc IP in a different subnet in the Red Server, expose the API in an unusual port (not 80), use client certificates, expose the API through SSL, and many other things to protect the server inside the firewall and the communication between servers.

That's the mission of the firewall. If not, you'd simply didn't connect the networks through the firewall.

Comment: Yup that would work if its in Intranet but we are talking about internet and silverlight is client side application. So basically whole application loads to client right and that try to do calls to webapi. Putting Mac filters are useless in this scenario right or putting webapi behind firewall (restricted intranet server). Am i missing something here? could you clarity because running packet analyzer says silverlight is totally client side.

Comment: The "There is a Silverlight Application in a server" made me think that the server had some kind of logic exposed to the Silverlight clients. In that case, I'd put that server out of the firewall communicating with the SQL Server through the firewall. However, it looks like your client app is speaking directly to SQL Server. Opening a SQL Server to internet is much more dangerous that opening a web server exposing functionalities trhough controlled endpoints. However, in your case, it looks like there is no other way to make your app sure, but a VLAN if clients are under your control